# How to see the amount of visits from mobile bookmarks

Tags: google-analytics, mobile

For my website I want to see in Google Analytics how many people have been visiting my website through a bookmark icon on their phone's screen. This way I can learn how many people have bookmarked my website - and treat it like an app.

Is there any way you guys can think of of how to track these visits?

Answer (score 1):

There is one loose way of doing this, find the direct mobile traffic to your site (since using bookmarks to return to the site will be interpreted as direct traffic).

A better way of doing this would be to add the urching tracking parameters (utm ones) to the bookmark icon and track that as a separate campaign.

Answer (score 0):

Where did the bookmark Icon on their phone come from? If it was something you created / installed, this would be an ideal situation for campaign / link tracking.